# How to ensure that when R writes to a csv file, column types are decimal despite NA values?

Tags: r, csv, powerbi

I'm using R to write a csv file, which is then ingested by PowerBi365 to fuel an existing report. One of the columns in the csv file ends up having some NA values, which means that PowerBi erroneously identifies the column as a string field. This prevents the application from being able to analyze the numerical data in the column. Is there a way to avoid this? I've tried using write.csv(x,file,na=""), but the problem persists. How can I write the csv in such a way that PowerBi365 recognizes the field as a number field? Thanks!

Comment: You could try other characters, maybe one of the common missing categories in surveys like na="-99999" if the elements of your column are positive. It would be event better if PowerBi365 had a character that it used for missing numbers...

Answer (score -1):

Turns out this problem was caused by the use of the Round() function in R. That function in combination with the existing NA values in the dataset caused the csv to assume that this particular column was a character field. I solved the problem by wrapping the Round() function in the function as.numeric(), which coerced the field back into num data type.

Comment: What `Round` function is this? The base `round` function returns a numeric.